# Tracking a dynamic ip address?

Tags: ip, tracking

Is it possible for someone to track a dynamic IP address, if so what would it take and how would it manifest?

Would the person doing so be able to log every change in your ip range and eventually end up with the whole set of ip's you are able to have?

Is it possible to make my dynamic ip change in a different pattern, say in a more extreme way, making it harder for someone to trace it as described above? Is it possible to encrypt it somehow, and also all other information such as hardware MAC's / Inet MAC etc. everything.

Comment: You would get a better response on Serverfault or Superuser imo.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes and no.

In most cases only your service provider (and law enforcement) will have a log of all IPs you had and start/end times of each lease. You basically can't do anything to prevent this because they need to be able to identify you as their customer with a valid contract. This is usually done via MAC address of CPE equipment you get from service provider or by some login credentials (for PPPoE for example). There is no such thing as encrypting the IP and changing your MAC address would not prevent service provider from identifying you. For someone else there is no reliable way to track you. The closest thing they can find is the scope (or scopes) from which dynamic IP addresses are issued.

At the other hand, when you mix the technology and psychology, every one of us leaves the unique fingerprint when browsing the web. If you examine the combination of software someone uses, their traffic patterns (amount of traffic, sites they visit, activity during the day), their behavior and style of writing, etc, you can not just link them to some IP address but make a distinction between different users behind the same IP address. Anyway collecting this data is really hard which makes it improbable, especially if we are talking about ordinary internet users.